# How to open a python program within python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm working on a program using tkinter (2.7) that when a button is clicked, it opens a separate python program. What I have been trying to do is give the button a command and define it as the separate program. This is what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import os

app = Tk()
app.title("iClassics")
app.geometry("450x300+200+200")


#Definitions
def mTetris():
   subprocess.Popen("Tetris.py")


#Heading
headlabel = Label(text="iClassics", font=("Times", 30), background=("blue")).pack()



#Buttons
buttontetris = Button(app, text="Tetris", command=mTetris).pack()
buttonpong = Button(app, text="Pong").pack()
buttonbrick = Button(app, text="Brick Breaker").pack()
buttonsnake = Button(app, text = "Snake").pack()






app.mainloop()
```

Why can't I open my tetris.py on click?

Comment: Do you get an error? What does the error say? Have you tried googling for the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).
You shoold call it this way:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "tetris.py"])
```

Comment: Do I have to put the full location of the file or just tetris.py?

Comment: @user3677715 This you can kindly test in just two steps instead of asking Fred, cannot you? You might want to know, that StackOverflow Netiquette encourages members to rather show their own efforts before (re)asking the Community. Members are keen to help, but rather on things, that are complex, troublesome, weird or otherwise hard to solve. Enjoy this high spirit of the StackOverflow and try to join on a cooperative wave.